# Initialize a class with default values when one parameter is a class

Tags: kotlin

```
kotlin 1.2.60
```

I have the following data classes and I want to initialize them with default values. However, I am unsure how can I initialize the Harddisk when its a class.

I have tried do the following, but this will create a new HeadDisk object, not something I want:

```
data class HeadDisk(var size: Float,
                    var manufacturer: Manufacturer)

data class Computer(var speed: Float = 0F,
                    var screenSize: Float = 0F,
                    var hardDisk: HeadDisk = HeadDisk())
```

I could set it to null by explicitly setting it as a null value. But I don't want to explicitly set this to null.

```
data class Computer(var speed: Float = 0F,
                    var screenSize: Float = 0F,
                    var hardDisk: HeadDisk? = null)
```

Or do the following with delegate:

```
data class Computer(var speed: Float = 0F,
                    var screenSize: Float = 0F) {

    var hardDisk: HeadDisk by Delegates.notNull()
}
```

Just wondering what is the best and simplest solution to this?

Comment: I'm confused as to what you want, you want to initialize it with an instance of HeadDisk, but you don't want to create a new instance of HeadDisk? Because that is how I interpret your question.

What exactly do you want the default value to be?

Comment: Your question is really unclear. What is the behaviour you want to see? I mean the last example forces the user to provide a value, so there is no defalult there. In the first example that attribute will always be a valid value and the user need not provide one. the one in the middle allows the user to provide a value, but if it does not then it has to handle the null case. All these are valid use cases but it all depends on what *you* want. IMHO "by default" I'd go with the simplest solution, i.e. number 1, because it is "the most type safe" and more uniform to use. But it depends...

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear. Basically, I wanted to set default values for initializing the class. That is why I specified the defaults values in the constructor. The question really was how to set a default value for the class HardDisk? I hope I am clearer now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your assumption is incorrect. Use

```
data class Computer(var speed: Float = 0F,
                    var screenSize: Float = 0F,
                    var hardDisk: HeadDisk = HeadDisk())
```

The default `HeadDisk()` is not created unless it's needed. The generated Java code for

```
class Foo
class Bar(val foo: Foo = Foo())
```

is

```
// $FF: synthetic method
public Bar(Foo var1, int var2, DefaultConstructorMarker var3) {
   if ((var2 & 1) != 0) { // this checks whether you called it with or without that parameter
      var1 = new Foo(); // a new one each time
   }
   this(var1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use the [null object pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_object_pattern) here I guess since delegates and lateinit vars are not supported in constructors. What I usually do is something like this:

// simple example

```
class Foo(val bar: String = NO_BAR) {

    // note the instance equality check
    fun hasBar() = bar !== NO_BAR

    companion object {

        val NO_BAR = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
    }
}
```

So I have a `val` which represents the `has no value` state.

Another solution is to use `Optional` or the `Option` data type from [Arrow](https://arrow-kt.io/docs/datatypes/option/)